# Can I Zip CloudFile File inside Azure File Shares?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-files

I have folders containing files in Azure File Shares, my need is to zip each file individually before downloading them to my local folder on the pc.

All the solutions I found are referred to files in Azure Blob containers and not my use case.

> Has anyone found a way to zip the file directly to Azure File Shares storage before downloading the file locally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Modified the format